# 'PSDataStreams' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, pypi, powershell-remoting

I want to execute powershell commands in a remote windows server using python.
I am using pypsrp for making connection to remote windows server, then executed
`client.execute_ps(f'Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned')`

got error -
`'PSDataStreams' object has no attribute 'decode'`

I am able to connect and copy files from local machine to remote window server -
client.copy(source_path, dest_path)

I am using pypsrp module to connect to a remote windows server -

```
try:
    with Client(server=self.ip, username=self.username, password=psw, auth='ntlm') as client:
    stdout, stderr, rc = client.execute_ps(f'Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned') 
    error = stderr.decode('utf-8').strip("\n")
    output = stdout.decode('utf-8').strip("\n")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Got error -
`'PSDataStreams' object has no attribute 'decode'`

When I print strout, its empty.
Stderr is -
`stderr ---- <pypsrp.powershell.PSDataStreams object at 0x0000014170402AF0>`

How to decode the value of stderr, or what is the correct code to execute powershell commands at remote window server.

Answer (score 0):

`execute_ps` doesn't support traditional strerr use execute_cmd instead. This is written in [execute_ps comment](https://github.com/jborean93/pypsrp/blob/master/src/pypsrp/client.py).

> Because this runs in a runspace, traditional concepts like stdout,
> stderr, rc's are no longer relevant. Instead there is a output,
> error/verbose/debug streams, and a boolean that indicates if the
> script execution came across an error. If you want the traditional
> stdout/stderr/rc, use execute_cmd instead.

So, you can get traditional strerr like this.

```
stdout, stderr, rc = client.execute_cmd('powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned')
```